# What type of database would be used for keeping data between a Web Site and Game Server?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm making an Online game where I will host a game server. Players will login to my game server. They will then be taken to a lobby where they can choose a game to join. I will be keeping track of wins and loses and a few other statistics.

My requirements are as follows:

- At any time in game, a player should be able to click on another
  player and get their latest up-to-date statistics.
- A player should also be able to go to my Web Site and get the same
  statistics. (Ideally, up to date immediately, but less important than
  in game)
- I will also have a leader-board that will be generated from data on
  the Web Site.

My question is: What type of solution would typically be used for this type of situation?

It is vital that I never lose data. One thing that worries me about using a Web Site database is data loss.

I'm also unsure how the interactions between the Web Site database and the game server would work. Is there a capability with mySQL to do this sort of thing? My other concern with using a Web Site database is how much bandwidth I would consume monthly. I generously estimate that I will have 1000 people online at any given time. A game lasts around 20 minutes.

How are these types of situations typically solved? I've looked all over but I've yet to find a clear answer to my concerns.

Thanks

Comment: I would also recommend you consider security if your game statistics are important enough to need to be current. You could have a look at OWASP top 10 security flaws developers need to defened against. You can disregard this comment if your game stats are fine being cheated. Specifically look at SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @Dessus what if the user never directly interacts with the database and the database can only be modified from the static server ip?

Comment: A user can interact with a database by entering information through a textbox. If I entered the correct sql into a textbox. It could (depending on how most ppl set it up) go directly to the database. It doesn't matter where your database is. Ultimately somehow you get data from your database to display/update. I could potentially use a sites own infrastructure to execute whatever sql I wanted (Unless you put in measures against SQL injection). Its actually a very frightening thing and I believe the news said it had been used in the attack on SONY where they lost peoples credit card details.

Comment: @Dessus What if I do not allow the string "sql" to be typed in the textbox?

Comment: The way round it generally could be to use parameterize queries. Ie feed your UI data into a sql parameter. If you remove sql keywords from your textbox that is a black list approach where you could miss certain key words that are introduce to sql. With securtity you really want a white list approach. ie one where only valid requests can only ever be valid. If you parameterize your sql requests, you can allow where to be entered into your textbox without security risks. See here: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html

Comment: That is a c# example but the same concept exists for probably all sql databases. Essentially let SQL filter its own bad charactes, its not something you want to do. You do need to make SQL do it by parameterizing your query for any variables input by users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend a few things based on your requirements. Your question is very open ended so the answers given are quite general:

1. Databases are fine to store data as they write to a harddrive and are transactional (meaning they fine to survive web server crashes).
2. Databases can be backed up using any one of numerous back up tools, such as: https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+backup&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a
3. For up to date statistics you should probably be pulling active game players information from a cache (otherwise you might find you are pounding the database when most of your data isnt going to change (ie possibly most gamers could be offline and their data will remain static but might want to be viewed.
4. Investigate what kind of database you want. NOSQL, or SQL. There is no obvious choice here without evaluating the benefits of each.
5. Investigate N-Tier or MultiTier design. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture
6. Consider some sort of cloud like infrastructure such as appfabric, azure, (there are other linux ones too) etc. There are many cloud services which can provide high scalability. It could be a short cut for the previous points.